# How are Threads created and managed by the HttpApplication?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, httpcontext, lifecycle, httpapplication

How are threads created and managed by the *HttpApplication* in ASP.NET?

What determines if an *HttpContext* opens a new thread or uses an existing thread?  How can this be controlled?

I will be happy with either a solid explanation or a link to a sufficient resource on this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How are Threads created and managed by the HttpApplication in ASP.NET?

They are drawn from a thread pool. They are not created at each request.

> What determines if an HttpContext opens a new thread or uses an existing thread?

New threads are never created. They are drawn from the pool and returned to it once the request has been serviced.

> How can this be controlled?

This is something that ASP.NET does very well and not something you want to control but you if you really insist on [here's an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163544.aspx) which explains how you could use STA threads instead of MTA threads in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent post from [Thomas Marquardt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/06/09/introduction.aspx) (a member of the Microsoft ASP.Net dev team who actually works on this very area) on ASP.NET thread use in IIS6 & IIS7:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx